# Top down strafing (facing mouse)

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, mouse, direction, trigonometry

How do I make my character strafe? He is always facing the mouse

```
        this.rotation = Math.atan2((stage.mouseY - this.y), (stage.mouseX - this.x)) * 180/ Math.PI + 90;
```

How do I make him strafe to the left when holding down a key?

```
            if(leftKeyDown)
            {
                if(!this.hitTestObject(_root.container_wall))
                {
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                    //WHAT TO TYPE HERE?
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know...

for left

```
x += Math.cos((rotation + 90)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
y += Math.sin((rotation + 90)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
```

for right

```
x += Math.cos((rotation - 90)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
y += Math.sin((rotation - 90)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
```

for back

```
x += Math.cos((rotation + 180)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
y += Math.sin((rotation + 180)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
```

for forward

```
x += Math.cos((rotation)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
y += Math.sin((rotation)*Math.PI/-180)*speed;
```

Comment: But i've just realized you already converted rotation to radians, so you don't need `Math.Pı/-180` stuff here.

Comment: The character only strafes if I have the mouse at a certain position. He doesn't always stafe in the right direction (sometimes he goes backwards when I hold down left, depending on where the mouse is).

Comment: You should realize there is no way to make what you want, think about it, you're looking for something impossible as logic.

Hah? Got it what you mean. But! You have to use stage3D or something like that, i mean, you have to use a platform which let's you change mouse pointer's position by your code. But pure flash doesn't let you control user's cursor point.

All you need is changing mouse position relative to player position.

Comment: But it does work logically. Strafing means the character just walks to the left or right, still facing the mouse. Essentially the character will orbit around the mouse..

Comment: ah, that's better, then probably the problem about you adding " + 90;"  to the your rotation et the end of your rotation setting function. You just try to add or subtract "90" from whole code lines i've sent you. i mean, change (rotation + 90) to (rotation + 90 - 90) or (rotation + 90 + 90)

Comment: Yes, I made it work by adding and subctracting here and there. So stupid of me not to try it before. THank you so much! :)